# How can DI water inhibit peroxidase activity?

Tags: water, biochemistry, analytical-chemistry, proteins, enzymes

I'm troubleshooting an IHC staining issue, and according to Thermo-Fischer's website, "Deionized water can sometimes contain peroxidase inhibitors that can significantly impair enzyme activity." What exactly could deionized water contain that would inhibit peroxidase?

Comment: Would be nice to have a link. Found this: https://www.thermofisher.com/se/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/ihc-troubleshooting-guide.html

Comment: I'll hazard a guess: minute amounts of heavy metals maybe? Oxygen (although that sounds farfetched)?

Comment: @BuckThorn, I think it must be leachates from the ion exchange resins and perhaps bacterial contamination. I don't think deionized water has traces of metals.

Comment: @M.Farooq Yes, good point. The presence of metals would violate the designation DI. I'll leave my comment up in case someone else has this odd thought.